# ASP.NET MVC 4 - Nested Models - How to set up proper associations?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm coming to asp.net MVC 4 from a background in Rails, and I am having some trouble figuring out how to deal with nested models.

I am using Entity Framework 4.3 with a CodeFirst approach.

The application is fairly simple and has a **Set** model - which has many **Franchises**.  And it has a Franchise model - which belongs to Sets.

The POCO classes were created along with the appropriate navigation properties, then I scaffolded the controllers with the views, then generated the database.

Here are the classes:

**Set**

```
 namespace FranchiseManagerTest.Models
    {
        public class Set
        {        
            [Key]
            public int SetID { get; set; }
            public string SetName { get; set; }
            public string MainAddress { get; set; }
            public string TimeZone { get; set; }       
            public virtual ICollection<Franchise> Franchises { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

**Franchise**

```
namespace FranchiseManagerTest.Models
{
    public class Franchise
    {
        [Key]
        public int FranchiseID { get; set; }        
        public int SetID { get; set; }
        public string FranchiseName { get; set; }
        public string FranchiseNumber { get; set; }     

        public virtual Set Set { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Then I created some test Franchise Sets and Franchises.

Here is the main view:

[image]

The project requires that all Franchises related to a Set are visible within the corresponding Set.  Also, I need to be able to add a Franchise to a Set while I am in the Set's details.

I created a screenshot to illustrate what it looks like after I click "details" on the main view:

[image]

The **New Franchise** button is created with an ActionLink that looks like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("New Franchise", "Create", "Franchise", null,  new { @class = "btn btn-large btn-primary" })
```

This takes me to the Franchise Create page that looks like this:

[image]

**The problem, as you can see, is that the dropdown that should contain the related Set Model is not pre-populated - instead I have to click the dropdown and re-select the Set that I am already in.**

**The dropdown *is* being populated - but by all existing Sets - instead of the Set that I am inside of.**

Here is the dropdown when I click on it:

[image]

Inside of the **Franchise Create View**, this is what that dropdown and its label look like:

```
       <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SetID, "Set")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("SetID", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SetID)
        </div>
```

**Here is what I have tried:**

---

I attempted to pass in a **SetID** value to the View using the ActionLink:

```
@Html.ActionLink("New Franchise", "Create", "Franchise", Model.SetID,  new { @class = "btn btn-large btn-primary" })
```

I then tried to change the String.Empty attribute of the Create View to this:

```
 <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SetID, "Set")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("SetID", Model.SetID)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SetID)
    </div>
```

However, this did not work and generated an **Invalid Argument** error.

**Here is a possible clue (or another issue?)**

When I visit the Create Franchise View from the associated Set that I am in, here is what the URL looks like:

[image]

I would assume that if the associations between **Set** and **Franchise** were correct, and when I went to add a Franchise within a Set, that the URL would look like this:

```
localhost:52987/Set/1/Franchise/Create
```

Is this a wrong assumption to make - is this possible to do in .NET MVC?

**Any advice here is greatly appreciated!**

---

**EDITS**

---

Here are the routes in my Global.asax file if this is helpful:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Set", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

As Requested - here are both the GET and POST Create methods of the Franchise Controller:

```
 //
    // GET: /Franchise/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.SetID = new SelectList(db.Sets, "SetID", "SetName");
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Franchise/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Franchise franchise)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Franchises.Add(franchise);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.SetID = new SelectList(db.Sets, "SetID", "SetName", franchise.SetID);
        return View(franchise);
    }
```

Just let me know if more code will be helpful.

Comment: What does your FranchiseController.Create method look like?

Comment: Hey Stripling - I've added the controller code to the Edit section of my OP.  It may very well be something with the controller - just not sure what.  I've tried putting a parameter for SetID into the GET Create method, but no luck.  Again - I'm sure I'm just doing it wrong.  I removed the parameter and this is what it looks like now.

Comment: You need to change your Create method the way justinb138 suggests. It needs to take in a `SetID` parameter so that the one you pass it from the link can be used as the default value in the dropdown. (you might even want to make it use a hidden input for that value instead of a dropdown, unless you expect people to change the Franchise)

Comment: Got it - seems to be working now.  I'll try the hidden input next.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a bit confused as to what you're looking to do, but I'd suggest a few changes:

I'd change this:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SetID, "Set")
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownList("SetID", Model.SetID)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SetID)
</div>
```

to this:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SetID, "Set")
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SetID, (SelectList)ViewBag.FranchiseSets)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SetID)
</div>
```

If you pass in the **SetID** value to your **Create** ActionMethod and assign it, it should get passed to the view.  It looks like you're not populating the DropDownList, so there's no option in the select list to be selected.

```
public ActionResult Create(int SetID)
{
    ViewBag.FranchiseSets = new SelectList(...);
    var franchise = new Franchise { SetID = SetID };
    return View(franchise);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  It's basically a simple CRUD app.  CRUD actions need to be performed on child elements while inside of the parent element.  The select list on the Create Franchise view actually is being populated by all existing Franchise Sets.  The problem is that I am creating the new Franchise within a Set - so that Set should already be shown within the dropdown, without the user having to click the drop-down and reselect the Set that they are already in.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Great - tried this and it seems to be working now.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear exactly how your actions and routes are set up, but you may want to try this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("New Franchise", "Create", "Franchise", new{Model.SetID},  new { @class = "btn btn-large btn-primary" })
```

By creating an object with a `SetID` property, MVC will know that the parameter is supposed to be named "SetID".

PS--may I suggest renaming `Set` to (`FranchiseSet`, or `FranchiseGroup`, etc.), to avoid naming collisions? `Set` [is one of the most ambiguous and common words](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/set?r=75&src=ref&ch=dic) in the English language.

Comment: Thanks for the comments - I just tried using the new {Model.SetId}, however that didn't work for me either unfortunately.  I will post the routes in my Global.asax file if you like - but they are the standard ones that are created by the framework.  I actually did have Set named to FranchiseSet in the beginning - but when the database was created, it would create FranchiseSet_ID instead of FranchiseSetID.  I could never get the associations to work until I changed the name.  I may try using "Franchiseset" instead.

Comment: @PhillipKregg: Regarding the database name: it might work better to name it `FranchiseSetId` instead of `FranchiseSetID`. The framework probably thinks it needs to add that underscore to differentiate the capital letters or something.